Square-integral involving Brownian bridge
Let $B(t)$ be a standard Brownian bridge on $[0,1]$. Let $x>0$ be a (small) parameter. What is the distribution of
$$
\int_0^{1-x} \left( B(t + x) - B(t) \right)^2 dt?
$$
As noted I am interested in the case when $x$ is "small", so one could assume that $x \to 0$ in some sense. I assume that the result should have something to do with the chi-square distribution, but how?

PS: Maybe it is more natural to ask for $\int_0^1 ((B(t+x) - B(t))^2 dt$, where the Brownian bridge is understood to be extended periodically such that $B(t+x)$ is always well-defined.

Just to clarify, are you expecting that there is some normalising factor $g(x)$ such that as $x \downarrow 0$, the distribution of the random variable $g(x)\int_0^{1-x} (B(t+x)-B(t))^2 , dt$ converges to a non-trivial probability distribution on $[0,\infty)$? ["trivial" would just be convergence to 0.] And are you expecting that this limiting distribution can be expressed in some "explicit" manner by some formula potentially involving other well-established distributions? If so, are you able to provide some explanation or intuition behind why you're expecting these things?

The expected value of the distribution should be $x$, since morally the limit as $x \to 0$ of the expression above is the quadratic variation of the Brownian bridge. Now, assume that $x = 1/N$ for $N$ large, and replace the integral above by a sum over $N$ equidistant points. For each $k$, the quantity $(B(k/N + x) - B(k/N))^2$ has essentially distribution $x \chi_1^2$. Summing over $k=1,...,N$ with weights $1/N$ gives a distribution $\frac{x}{N} \chi_N^2$, which is concentrated around mean $x$ plus a $\mathcal{N}(0,2 \sqrt{x}/\sqrt{N})$ random variable, if I am not mistaken.

No, wait... in the end it should say $\mathcal{N}(0,2x)$ random variable, I hope it's correct like that. Anyway, of course all of this is not a precise calculation, since it completely ignores the dependence structure of the Brownian bridge. But it should give a rough idea about what to expect.
